How do I do a fuzzy search in neo4j
I am using NEO4J in my RAG application. I do an entity search in NEO4J. The entity name can take various forms. For example if the entity name is CY 2023, it can come as CY2023, CY23, CY   2023. How do I search so that I hit the same node with these different names.

If you are asking a general question about searching for nodes in Neo4j: here is an example of how you can use a Cypher regex to find all Foo-labelled nodes having a name value starting with "CY" and ending with "23":
MATCH (f:Foo)
WHERE f.name =~ "CY.*23"
RETURN f

